# Get gps coordinates for google maps

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-maps-api-3

I have an HTML form in my website with a field  the GPS coordinates.  How can I get the coordinates so that I can plot them on Google Maps, and persist them to a database?

Comment: What coordinates exactly?...TopLeft corner's, Center's,etc.. ?

Comment: Can you state the question more clearly? Are you accepting the co-ordinates as input from the user? Or do you want to determine the co-ordinates of the user?

Comment: i zqnt the user to click on the map and the coordinates goes to the address field in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look into the Geocoder section of the Google Maps V3 API.  I just went through this issue myself. When building your form, include hidden inputs for lat and long (whatever your field names in your db) like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[Location][lat]"  id="LocationLat"/>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Location][lon]"  id="LocationLon"/>
```

In your address input, you will say something like this:

```
<input name="data[Location][address]" onChange="getLatLong(address)" size="50" maxlength="255" type="text"/>
```

where you include the call to a javascript function called getLatLong().
Here is an example below of the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

 var geocoder;
 var add = document.getElementById("LocationAddress");

 function getLatLong(address){
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


  geocoder.geocode({ 'address':address},function(results, status){

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            document.getElementById("LocationLat").value=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
              document.getElementById("LocationLon").value=results[0].geometry.location.lng();


          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);

}
   });

 }
 </script>
```

You may need to play around with it a bit.  be sure to do a search for the google Geocoder here on SO, as I found my solution with bits and pieces I got straight from this site.

Comment: Excuse me but how i add the map to locate the coordinates

Comment: With what you have asked a user above, you seem to be looking to do something other than what I suggested.  Please remember to state your question very clearly in the future, as what you want is very different from what I was suggesting.    If you need to know how to add a google map to your page, I suggest you take a look at the Google Map V3's API pages.  As far as capturing the geocoordinates and storing them into a database, perhaps someone else on SO can help you.  Good luck and happy coding!